# What does the Type parameter in IEnumerable<T>.Intersect<T> do?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, types

I have a method:

```
public static bool ItemsIntersectOrFirstIsEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    if (source.Any())
    {
        return source.Intersect(target).Any();
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I see that you can pass a type to Intersect() so the return line in the first condition would be:

```
return source.Intersect<T>(target).Any();
```

How would that be different from my original code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explicitly specifying the parameter type makes no difference at all; `source` is an `IEnumerable<T>` and [`Intersect<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, so the [parameter type can be inferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) by the compiler without requiring it to be explicitly defined.

You can of course include the parameter type if you like, but sometimes this may make code *noisier / harder to read*. If you were to be explicit about all parameter types, the method would look like

```
public static bool ItemsIntersectOrFirstIsEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    if (source.Any<T>())
    {
        return source.Intersect<T>(target).Any<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```